# error .ExecuteNonQuery(); c# y mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

hola buenas noches a todos, mi pregunta es la siguiente estoy haciendo un pequeño crud en c# y mysql, el detalle es que cuando le doy click en guardar al formulario me manda este error.

este es mi codigo del boton guardar...

```
private void btnguardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //mandar  llama la conexion la clase
        conn.conexion.Obtener();
        //se genera la cadena de conexio para insert
        string query = "INSERT INTO `clientes`(`nombre`, `apellidos`, `telefono`) VALUES ('"+txtnombre.Text+"','"+txtapellido.Text+"','"+txttelefono.Text+"');";
        MySqlCommand guardar = new MySqlCommand(query, conn.conexion.Obtener());     
        guardar.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //se cierra la conexion
        MessageBox.Show("se guardo correcatemente");
        conn.conexion.Obtener().Close();
    }
```

/// bueno este es codigo del boton guardar...
y este es el codigo de mi cadena de conexion la estoy haciendo con clases...

```
namespace gym0._1.conn
{
    public class conexion  // se declara la clase como publica para que pueda entrar a cualquier parte del programa
    {
        public static MySqlConnection Obtener() // se genera el metodo
        {
            MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("Server = 127.0.0.1; database=gym; Uid=root; Pwd=admin; Port=3307;");
            conectar.Open();
            return conectar;
        }
    }
}
```

y bueno esta es la imagen que me da el error....
este es el resultado

[image: Error que me sale]

Comment: Deberias de mostrar un poco de tu base de datos, ya que el error radica en que no le envias un parametro que es necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un constraint en tu base de datos que no te permite insertar esos datos (clientes_ibfk1) el cual te requiere que el id del cliente este referenciado en la tabla de productos.

Por los nombres de las tablas intuyo que este FK esta mal planteado, es posible que lo hayas echo al reves.

Lo mejor que puedes hacer para diagnosticar el problema es ir al servidor SQL e intentar hacer la misma query directamente ahi. Si usas Workbench puedes generar el diagrama de tablas y quizas asi sea mas visual y lo encuentres mejor.